# Android SQLite get value from column

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a column ShopName, and another column called LocationCode, if the LocationCode equals to "SKP", the corresponding `ShopName` will be added to an array, my question is, how can I do that?

I got something like this:

```
public List<String> getQuotes() {
    String WhiteFarm = "WhiteFarm";
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM WhereToEat WHERE 'LocationCode' = " + WhiteFarm, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        list.add(cursor.getString(0));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return list;
}
```

And another class like this:

```
public class DatabaseGrabber extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.selection_main);

    final TextView Shop_name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ShopName);

    DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
    databaseAccess.open();
    final List<String> ShopName = databaseAccess.getQuotes();
    databaseAccess.close();

    Button StartDraw = (Button)findViewById(R.id.draw_start);
    StartDraw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Collections.shuffle(ShopName);
            String random = ShopName.get(0);
            Shop_name.setText(random);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: can we have code please?

Comment: put your code here it will help to understand it better

Comment: "get value from column" and "add to array"  are separate tasks. Which one is your question?

Comment: Query ShopName where LocationCode = 'SKP'  will return Cursor object. you can iterate cursor object and make array of ShopName

Comment: Misplaced apostrophes in your query.

Answer (score 1):

If your LocationCode contains a String (or TEXT for SQLite) type of data then your value should be enclosed in a single quote as shown in the code below:

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM WhereToEat WHERE LocationCode = " + "'" + WhiteFarm "'", null);
```